# Upload file does not work - cURL & PHP

Tags: php, curl

My code to upload the file on the REMOTE server doesn't seem to be working. When uploading the file from the browser at the link, all the contents of `csv` file is committed to the database. Here is the code:

```
function postToDB()
{
  $fp = fopen('./errorLog.txt', 'w+');
  $csvFile = fopen('./myFile.csv', 'r');
  $url="http://abc.com/UploadCSVLogin/";

  $ch=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, ":password");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $csvFile);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);

  if (!curl_exec($ch))
     echo "Error: ".curl_error($ch);
  else
     echo "Success";
  curl_close($ch);
}
```

Strangely, the code echoes "Success". But I don't find the database updates taking place with the code above even though "Success" is echoed.

Can anyone help me find the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your submitting the raw CSV data, and its not encoded into field=value pairs as form post data is. The easiest way to deal with this is on the server to just use:

```
$csvfile = file_get_contents("php//input");
```

Comment: You can, but you need to read up on RFC 2616
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Comment: Also since your posting a file, you need to look at RFC 1341 - http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

Comment: Or, you could give this class a go, not sure though if it works as I just googled it for you - http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3753-PHP-Upload-files-via-HTTP-POST-using-Curl.html